# Displaying a different user control when button is clicked in current user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have two user controls say, UC1 and UC2. I have a Main Window. At the start of the application, UC1 is visible to the user. When the user clicks on a button in UC1, UC1 should disappear and UC2 should be displayed in the same window. I tried the following:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
 mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Test" WindowState="Maximized"> 
<Grid>
    <my:UC1 />
    <my:UC2 Visibility="Collapsed"/>      
</Grid>
```

Initially both the UCs are visible at the same time, so I made UC2 Collapsed. Now I want to make it Visible again when a button in UC1 is clicked. I am unable to access the Visibility of UC2 from UC1.

UC1.xaml.cs

```
  private void button2_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        // What to write here?
    }
```

**EDIT**

For 2 controllers UC1 and UC2 the use of Tag property works fine. Now I add another controller UC3 which is visible only after a different button is clicked.

So, finally I have UC1, UC2 and UC3 out of which only UC1 is visible. UC1 has two buttons, one click on 1st button only UC2 should be visible and on the click on the 2nd button, only UC3 should be visible.

I am not able to bind multiple tags. Is there a multiple tags converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
Posting the entire code to make the answer more clear. And I don't get any exceptions too.

**MainWindow.xaml :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:h="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <h:UC1 x:Name="Uc1" />
        <h:UC2 x:Name="Uc2" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs :**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**UC1.xaml :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UC1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Margin="65,113,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Fill="CornflowerBlue"
                 Stroke="Black" />
        <Button Width="75"
                Margin="177,239,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                Content="ABCD" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UC1.xaml.cs :**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UC_.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UC1 : UserControl
    {
        public UC1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window parentWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            if (parentWindow.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                (parentWindow as MainWindow).Uc1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                (parentWindow as MainWindow).Uc2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UC2.xaml :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication4.UC2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Margin="169,22,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Fill="Orange"
                 Stroke="Black" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UC2.xaml.cs :**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UC2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UC2 : UserControl
    {
        public UC2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives me null reference exception at 'parentWindow as MainWindow'

Comment: @DeepikaDixit you need to set the name of `UC1` and `UC2` in your xaml. `<my:UC1 Name="UC1" /><my:UC2 Name="UC2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>`

Comment: Yes, I have set the names.

Comment: I have edited it. Added xaml code also. Works fine for me.

If it still does not work. I will post the entire solution code.

Comment: @ViVi thats exactly what I did. But never mind the solution posted by Jai worked. I will still try this again since its simpler and try to debug my null exception. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to know that you got the solution. Anyways I have tested your code to ensure it works. :)

Comment: @ViVi I am still getting the Null Reference Exception. The button is in UC1 just to be clear. Thanks!

Comment: I am posting the entire code for your reference. And it's working entirely fine here. Just to ensure. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Grid>
    <my:UC1 Name="UC1" />
    <my:UC2 Name="UC2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>      
</Grid>

private void button2_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.UC1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    this.UC2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

### Edit:

Just realized that your button is in UC1. There are many ways to do this, but this is probably one way that has the least codes.

```
<Grid>
    <my:UC2 Name="UC2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <my:UC1 Tag="{Binding ElementName=UC2}" />
</Grid>

private void button2_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    var uc2 = this.Tag as UC2;
    if (uc2 != null)
        uc2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This method is shortest but it may be harder for someone else to figure out what you wrote.

If you want a good method, do it at the `MainWindow`, bind `UC2`'s `Visibility` to `UC1`'s, and use a converter.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:VisibilityInversionConverter x:Key="VisibilityInversionConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <my:UC1 Name="UC1" />
    <my:UC2 Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UC1, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityInversionConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: What if I now want a new User Control UC3 to also be dependent on UC1? Can I add multiple Tag bindings?

Comment: @DeepikaDixit Nope... This works just for this scenario. If you want to do this multiple times, you should use a converter suggested by [AnjumSKhan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38090842/2970960). His solution actually works - just let UC2 bind to UC1's visibility (with converter). When UC1 is visible, UC2 is not. When UC1's button is clicked, make the event make itself(UC1) collapsed. This will automatically make UC2 visible because its visibility bound to UC1's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. The second UC depends upon first one, so you need a `Binding`.
2. Write an `IValueConverter` to toggle `Visibility` , so that there remains no dependency between the two UC.

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
      <local:ToggleVisConv x:Key="ConvKey"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <local:UserControl1 x:Name="UC1"/>
       <local:UserControl2 Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=UC1, Converter={StaticResource ConvKey}}"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

Converter code :

```
public class ToggleVisConv : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility v = (Visibility)value;
        if (v == Visibility.Collapsed)
            return Visibility.Visible;

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to toggle the visibility only when the button is clicked. Also there is another User Controller UC3 which needs to toggle when a different button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with use of  dependency property

Xaml:

```
     <StackPanel>
     <vm:UC1 GetUserControl2="{Binding ElementName=usrUC2}"  x:Name="usrUC1"/>
     <vm:UC2  x:Name="usrUC2"/>
     </StackPanel>
```

Class:

```
public partial class UC1 : UserControl
{
    public UC1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GetUserControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("GetUserControl2", typeof(UserControl),
    typeof(UC1), null);

    public UserControl GetUserControl2
    {
        get
        {
            return (UserControl)GetValue(GetUserControlProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GetUserControlProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         GetUserControl2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```